# Partial depth comparison between two objects

Tags: javascript, json

The use of JavaScript to achieve the depth of two objects is comapre, if true is not equal to equal returns, returns false. The first parameter compare to the original object, second parameters for the comparison of the target object, the object attribute exists in value only exists, the property does not exist in the original object if the object, it will return directly false. Here are some examples.

```
const object = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'test',
    product: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'product'
    },
    updatedAt: 'now'
};
const objectA = {
    name: 'test',
    product: {
        name: 'product'
    }
};
const objectB = {
    name: 'test',
    product: {
        name: 'anotherProduct'
    }
};
compare(object, objectA) // return true
compare(object, objectB) // return false
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i made,
fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/jayjoshi64/qn70yosx/5/

it has recursive function which will check if two given object is object or one of implicit object.

if it is object, it will again check recursively if they are same.
code of the function compare..

it is working for your objects.!

```
function compare(first,second)  
{
    //alert("once");
    var flag=true;

if(typeof second=='object')
{
    //if the variable is of type object
    if(typeof first!='object')
    {
            flag=false

    }
    else
    {
     //check every key of object

      $.each(second, function(key, value) {
             //if socond's key is available in first.  
            if(first.hasOwnProperty(key))
            {
                //recursive call for the value.
                if(!compare(first[key],second[key]))
                {
                    flag=false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                flag=false
            }
        });
        }
    }
    else
    {
            // if two objects are int,string,float,bool.
            if(first!=second)
        {
                flag=false;
        }

    }
  return(flag);

}
```